# Clustering brands using words embeddings

Tags: python

Ok, so the title might sound a bit confusing, but here's an analogy of what I'm trying to achieve. Let's imagine that we have the following dataset:

| Brand name | Product type | Product_Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Nike | Shoes | These black shoes are wonderful. They are elegant, and really comfortable |
| BMW | Car | This car goes fast. If you like speed, you'll like it. |
| Suzuki | Car | A family car, elegant and made for long journeys. |
| Call of Duty | VideoGame | A nervous shooter, putting you in the shoes of a desperate soldier, who has nothing left to lose. |
| Adidas | Shoes | Sneakers made for men, and women, who always want to go out with style. |

This is just a made-up sample, but let's imagine this list goes on for a lot of other products.

What I'm trying to achieve here, is to cluster the elements (whether it is shoes, cars, or videogames), based on the words used in their respective description. Thus, I would obtain brands that are clustered together according to their description, but perhaps not belonging to the same type (e.g.: Suzuki + Adidas), and to get the name of the brands that are clustered together.

To do so, I relied on a word embedding method. After cleaning the description (stop words, non-alphanumeric characters) and tokenized it, I used a FastText model (the Wikipedia one) to evaluate the embeddings in the product descriptions.

```
def clean_text(text, tokenizer, stopwords):
    text = str(text).lower()  # Lowercase words
    text = re.sub(r"\[(.*?)\]", "", text)  # Remove [+XYZ chars] in content
    text = re.sub(r"\s+", " ", text)  # Remove multiple spaces in content
    text = re.sub(r"\w+…|…", "", text)  # Remove ellipsis (and last word)
    text = re.sub(r"<a[^>]*>(.*?)</a>", r"\1", text) #Remove html tags
    text = re.sub(f"[{re.escape(punctuation)}]", "", text)
    text = re.sub(r"(?<=\w)-(?=\w)", " ", text)  # Replace dash between words
    text = re.sub(
        f"[{re.escape(string.punctuation)}]", "", text
    )  # Remove punctuation
    doc = nlp_model(text)
    tokens = [token.lemma_ for token in doc]
    #tokens = tokenizer(text)  # Get tokens from text
    tokens = [t for t in tokens if not t in stopwords]  # Remove stopwords
    tokens = ["" if t.isdigit() else t for t in tokens]  # Remove digits
    tokens = [t for t in tokens if len(t) > 1]  # Remove short tokens
    return tokens #Clean the Text

def sent_vectorizer(sent, model): 
    sent_vec =[]
    numw = 0
    for w in sent:
        try:
            if numw == 0:
                sent_vec = model[w]
            else:
                sent_vec = np.add(sent_vec, model[w])
            numw+=1
        except:
            pass

    return np.asarray(sent_vec) / numw

df = pd.read_csv("./mockup.csv")
custom_stopwords = set(stopwords.words("english"))
df["Product_Description"] = df["Product_Description"].fillna("")
df["tokens"] = df["Product_Description"].map(lambda x: clean_text(x, word_tokenize, custom_stopwords))
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('./wiki-news-300d-1M.vec')
```

The problem is that I'm a bit of a beginner in word embeddings and clustering. As I said, my goal would be to cluster brands according to the words used in their description (the hypothesis is perhaps some brands are linked together through the words used in their description?), thus forgoing the old classification (shoes, cars, videogames...). I would also like to get the key brands of each cluster (so cluster 1 = Suzuki + Adidas, Cluster 2 = Call of Duty + Nike, Cluster 3 = BMW + ..., etc...).

Does anyone have any ideas on how to tackle this problem? I read several tutorials online on word embeddings and clustering, and to be completely honest, I am a bit lost.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So the technique that will likely be most useful is k-means clustering, but I have not done this with 'words' being your data points instead of w, x, y, z coordinates in space.  I am interested in the issue though, so I am looking for whether there is module in Python that somehow assigns numbers to the words for you.  I have thoughts as to how you could do it yourself, but a module would be easier.  Will revert in 30 minutes.

Comment: So an example of K-Means Clustering using Python is given here https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/kmeans-text-clustering/.  Once you have determined your centroids (i.e., the center of mass of your clusters), you can then proceed to measure each individual brand's description's 'distance' (for lack of a better term) from each of those centroids in order to ascertain which center of mass it is associated with.